# Hibernate one application? (save state)

Tags: savestate

Is there software which allows to hibernate (save state) of the specific application and then recreate it (maybe on other computer)?

Is it possible to write such type of application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is not possible in general. This would be a very intrusive software :)

It'd require a lot of support from the underlaying OS and even with this support it'd be not that easy. Even if you manage to gather and save a process memory (user and kernel space) which some OSs will allow you to do with an existing APIs, it would be very difficult, well, even impossible to restore it just like this.

The only way to go without writing really complex stuff would be to use virtual machine software. Using this approach would allow you to achieve what you want.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's usually called serialization. Most languages will have a library for it.

Comment: But what i mean is to save state of whole running application e.g. with filled textboxes, even while calculating some data. You can hibernate windows, I'd like to hibernate only one application. So is it possible to get all memory used by application and save it to hard disk?

Comment: It might be, but in your question you suggested being able to reawaken the application on a different computer. Serialization would make this possible because it can be portable. Do you really have so much application data that it isn't feasible to serialize it?